# Why my code is not doing the math correctly? I don't understand how it's making the calcs and using my data

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, dataframe, dataset

I am trying to calculate the difference between points scored and allowed by a basketball team in the span of a month. I have a dataset I personally created with columns for the home team, home score, away team, and away score. The averages need to comprehend both home and away games.

This is the dataset I'm using as input:

|  | ...1 | game_id | date | round | home_team | home_score | away_team | away_score | +/- | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 635676 | 2010-10-16 | Round 1 | Teramo Basket | 83 | Olimpia Milano | 89 | -6 | L |
| 2 | 2 | 635669 | 2010-10-17 | Round 1 | JuveCaserta Basket | 87 | Pallacanestro Biella | 91 | -4 | L |
| 3 | 3 | 635670 | 2010-10-17 | Round 1 | Sutor Basket Montegranaro | 88 | Dinamo Basket Sassari | 76 | 12 | W |
| 4 | 4 | 635671 | 2010-10-17 | Round 1 | Pallacanestro Treviso | 88 | S.S. Felice Scandone | 70 | 18 | W |
| 5 | 5 | 635672 | 2010-10-17 | Round 1 | Pallacanestro Varese | 87 | Victoria Libertas | 78 | 9 | W |
| 6 | 6 | 635673 | 2010-10-17 | Round 1 | Virtus Pallacanestro Bologna | 68 | Pallacanestro Cantù | 66 | 2 | W |
| 7 | 7 | 635674 | 2010-10-17 | Round 1 | Pallacanestro Virtus Roma | 86 | New Basket Brindisi | 61 | 25 | W |
| 8 | 8 | 635675 | 2010-10-17 | Round 1 | Guerino Vanoli Basket | 68 | Mens Sana 1871 Basket | 71 | -3 | L |
| 9 | 9 | 635668 | 2010-10-23 | Round 2 | Dinamo Basket Sassari | 92 | JuveCaserta Basket | 87 | 5 | W |
| 10 | 10 | 635661 | 2010-10-24 | Round 2 | S.S. Felice Scandone | 85 | Pallacanestro Varese | 69 | 16 | W |
| 11 | 11 | 635662 | 2010-10-24 | Round 2 | Pallacanestro Biella | 79 | Teramo Basket | 70 | 9 | W |
| 12 | 12 | 635663 | 2010-10-24 | Round 2 | Pallacanestro Cantù | 77 | Guerino Vanoli Basket | 75 | 2 | W |
| 13 | 13 | 635664 | 2010-10-24 | Round 2 | Olimpia Milano | 80 | Pallacanestro Treviso | 65 | 15 | W |
| 14 | 14 | 635665 | 2010-10-24 | Round 2 | Victoria Libertas | 76 | Pallacanestro Virtus Roma | 69 | 7 | W |
| 15 | 15 | 635666 | 2010-10-24 | Round 2 | Mens Sana 1871 Basket | 93 | Sutor Basket Montegranaro | 82 | 11 | W |
| 16 | 16 | 635667 | 2010-10-24 | Round 2 | New Basket Brindisi | 87 | Virtus Pallacanestro Bologna | 84 | 3 | W |
| 17 | 17 | 635660 | 2010-10-30 | Round 3 | Pallacanestro Varese | 87 | Mens Sana 1871 Basket | 86 | 1 | W |
| 18 | 18 | 635653 | 2010-10-31 | Round 3 | New Basket Brindisi | 64 | Guerino Vanoli Basket | 71 | -7 | L |
| 19 | 19 | 635654 | 2010-10-31 | Round 3 | JuveCaserta Basket | 89 | Victoria Libertas | 91 | -2 | L |
| 20 | 20 | 635655 | 2010-10-31 | Round 3 | Sutor Basket Montegranaro | 79 | Pallacanestro Treviso | 72 | 7 | W |
| 21 | 21 | 635656 | 2010-10-31 | Round 3 | Teramo Basket | 77 | Dinamo Basket Sassari | 79 | -2 | L |
| 22 | 22 | 635657 | 2010-10-31 | Round 3 | Virtus Pallacanestro Bologna | 73 | S.S. Felice Scandone | 66 | 7 | W |
| 23 | 23 | 635658 | 2010-10-31 | Round 3 | Pallacanestro Virtus Roma | 66 | Pallacanestro Cantù | 78 | -12 | L |
| 24 | 24 | 635659 | 2010-10-31 | Round 3 | Pallacanestro Biella | 72 | Olimpia Milano | 81 | -9 | L |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Using R, I tried this code. I know the names of the columns are not the real stat I'm calculating, but I'm just testing now:

```
# Calcs of ORTG, DRTG, NETRTG:
monthly_averages <- ott_10 %>%
  group_by(home_team) %>%
  summarize(ORTG = mean(home_score), DRTG = mean(away_score))

monthly_averages_a <- ott_10 %>%
  group_by(away_team) %>%
  summarize(AORTG = mean(away_score), ADRTG = mean(home_score))

monthly_averages <- monthly_averages %>%
  mutate(AORTG = monthly_averages_a$AORTG, ADRTG = monthly_averages_a$ADRTG)
  
monthly_averages <- monthly_averages %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ORTG = mean(c(ORTG, AORTG)), DRTG = mean(c(DRTG, ADRTG)))
```

Most probably this code is not efficient, so any advice is appreciated, but it should do its job for this easy operation.

This is the Python code I created instead. My expectation is that the "Dinamo Basket Sassari" (the first row) has the following values: 82.3, 84.0, and -1.7.
The equation I'm trying to replicate is `(home_score + away_score)/3` (since I have data from three games). home and away score reference to that specific team of course.

Here's the code:

```
def avg_scored_allowed(df):
    # Calculate average points scored for each team
    home_score_avg = df.groupby('home_team')['home_score'].mean()
    away_score_avg = df.groupby('away_team')['away_score'].mean()

    # Calculate average points allowed for each team
    home_allowed_avg = df.groupby('home_team')['away_score'].mean()
    away_allowed_avg = df.groupby('away_team')['home_score'].mean()

    # Combine home and away stats
    average_scored = (home_score_avg + away_score_avg) / 2
    average_allowed = (home_allowed_avg + away_allowed_avg) / 2

    # Create a DataFrame to hold the results
    output = pd.DataFrame({
        'Team': average_scored.index,
        'Average Scored': average_scored.values,
        'Average Allowed': average_allowed.values
    })
```

These two output the same dataframe, which is the following:

|  | "...1" | "game_id" | "date" | "round" | "home_team" | "home_score" | "away_team" | "away_score" | "+/-" | "outcome" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 635676 | 2010-10-16 | "Round 1" | "Teramo Basket" | 83 | "Olimpia Milano" | 89 | -6 | "L" |
| 2 | 2 | 635669 | 2010-10-17 | "Round 1" | "JuveCaserta Basket" | 87 | "Pallacanestro Biella" | 91 | -4 | "L" |
| 3 | 3 | 635670 | 2010-10-17 | "Round 1" | "Sutor Basket Montegranaro" | 88 | "Dinamo Basket Sassari" | 76 | 12 | "W" |
| 4 | 4 | 635671 | 2010-10-17 | "Round 1" | "Pallacanestro Treviso" | 88 | "S.S. Felice Scandone" | 70 | 18 | "W" |
| 5 | 5 | 635672 | 2010-10-17 | "Round 1" | "Pallacanestro Varese" | 87 | "Victoria Libertas" | 78 | 9 | "W" |
| 6 | 6 | 635673 | 2010-10-17 | "Round 1" | "Virtus Pallacanestro Bologna" | 68 | "Pallacanestro Cantù" | 66 | 2 | "W" |
| 7 | 7 | 635674 | 2010-10-17 | "Round 1" | "Pallacanestro Virtus Roma" | 86 | "New Basket Brindisi" | 61 | 25 | "W" |
| 8 | 8 | 635675 | 2010-10-17 | "Round 1" | "Guerino Vanoli Basket" | 68 | "Mens Sana 1871 Basket" | 71 | -3 | "L" |
| 9 | 9 | 635668 | 2010-10-23 | "Round 2" | "Dinamo Basket Sassari" | 92 | "JuveCaserta Basket" | 87 | 5 | "W" |
| 10 | 10 | 635661 | 2010-10-24 | "Round 2" | "S.S. Felice Scandone" | 85 | "Pallacanestro Varese" | 69 | 16 | "W" |
| 11 | 11 | 635662 | 2010-10-24 | "Round 2" | "Pallacanestro Biella" | 79 | "Teramo Basket" | 70 | 9 | "W" |
| 12 | 12 | 635663 | 2010-10-24 | "Round 2" | "Pallacanestro Cantù" | 77 | "Guerino Vanoli Basket" | 75 | 2 | "W" |
| 13 | 13 | 635664 | 2010-10-24 | "Round 2" | "Olimpia Milano" | 80 | "Pallacanestro Treviso" | 65 | 15 | "W" |
| 14 | 14 | 635665 | 2010-10-24 | "Round 2" | "Victoria Libertas" | 76 | "Pallacanestro Virtus Roma" | 69 | 7 | "W" |
| 15 | 15 | 635666 | 2010-10-24 | "Round 2" | "Mens Sana 1871 Basket" | 93 | "Sutor Basket Montegranaro" | 82 | 11 | "W" |
| 16 | 16 | 635667 | 2010-10-24 | "Round 2" | "New Basket Brindisi" | 87 | "Virtus Pallacanestro Bologna" | 84 | 3 | "W" |
| 17 | 17 | 635660 | 2010-10-30 | "Round 3" | "Pallacanestro Varese" | 87 | "Mens Sana 1871 Basket" | 86 | 1 | "W" |
| 18 | 18 | 635653 | 2010-10-31 | "Round 3" | "New Basket Brindisi" | 64 | "Guerino Vanoli Basket" | 71 | -7 | "L" |
| 19 | 19 | 635654 | 2010-10-31 | "Round 3" | "JuveCaserta Basket" | 89 | "Victoria Libertas" | 91 | -2 | "L" |
| 20 | 20 | 635655 | 2010-10-31 | "Round 3" | "Sutor Basket Montegranaro" | 79 | "Pallacanestro Treviso" | 72 | 7 | "W" |
| 21 | 21 | 635656 | 2010-10-31 | "Round 3" | "Teramo Basket" | 77 | "Dinamo Basket Sassari" | 79 | -2 | "L" |
| 22 | 22 | 635657 | 2010-10-31 | "Round 3" | "Virtus Pallacanestro Bologna" | 73 | "S.S. Felice Scandone" | 66 | 7 | "W" |
| 23 | 23 | 635658 | 2010-10-31 | "Round 3" | "Pallacanestro Virtus Roma" | 66 | "Pallacanestro Cantù" | 78 | -12 | "L" |
| 24 | 24 | 635659 | 2010-10-31 | "Round 3" | "Pallacanestro Biella" | 72 | "Olimpia Milano" | 81 | -9 | "L" |

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: What are you trying to ask here? There's no question above

Comment: @Zero I'm sorry, I think that editing the question I removed a piece of text by mistake. it should be good now - maybe I wrote too much by Julien 's link standards, but I think it's too late now ahahah

Comment: @Cecic, I meant, you are writing multiple things but not asking any. You have provided two code snippets and provided only current and expected output. There are no input values to test against. And you are just asking what are you doing. If you have a problem with two different code snippets (albeit the functionality is the same but the programming language is different), it's better to write two separate questions so as not to confuse the reader.

Comment: @Zero Ok I'll try to be clearer. I don't know what is the issue with my code; I am excpeting an output but the math is simply wrong and I don't know why, if I'm mistaken or the code is bugged. I honestly don't know how else can I say this.

Comment: understood, can't say much without input data, but that's most likely because you're doing all the calculations separately and trying to combine it.

Comment: Don't you think your input and output DataFrames are same?

Comment: @Zero Yeah I'm pretty sure they are, I only have this dataframe in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say much without input data to test the code on. It may be a problem in calculating separately and combining directly.

```
def avg_scored_allowed(df):
    # Calculate the average points scored for each team
    output = df.groupby(['home_team', 'away_team']).aggregate({
        'home_score': 'mean',
        'away_score': 'mean'
    })

    output['average'] = (output['home_score'] + output['home_score'])/2
```

Combined all your calculations, rather than doing them individually and combining them later on. Try this out if it works for you.

Comment: I'll add my input data, in .csv format to the question as it is too long for this comment. Sorry for not sending it earlier, as you probably can see this is my first ever post in this forum :( Thanks for the tip tough, I'l try it right now!